# While Stying Flex-1 doesn't work while working with React Native on an android phone

Tags: react-native, flexbox

My code: -

```
    <View className="flex-row items-center space-x-2 pb-2 mx-4">
      <View className="flex-row space-x-2 bg-gray-200 p-3 flex-1">
        <SearchIcon color="gray" size={20} />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Restaurants and Cusines"
          keyboardType="default"
        />
      </View>

      <AdjustmentsIcon color="#00CCBB" />
    </View>
```

also I am using tailwind-css but I also checked it with normal stying it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

React Native [styling system](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style) differs from traditional css. Elements use the `style` prop, which expects an object or an array of objects (take a look at the styling link).  If you must use tailwind, you will want to find some way to convert the css styles into the react native styling system or to find [port](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react%20native%20tailwind) of tailwind for react native

Comment: I also tried the same using style prop but it didn't work there too

Comment: Tailwind or even regular css isnt supported out of the box by react native. Take a look a [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style). I've also update the answer

Answer (score 0):

For the `flex-1` to work the relationship should be `siblings` not `parent-child.` And the parent display of the siblings should be flex

```
Parent   // display flex
 - child // display flex-none or flex-1 or flex-auto
 - child // display flex-none or flex-1 or flex-auto
```

In you present code hierarchy is a `view` is inside another `view`:

```
- View
  - View
```

For things to work , try:

```
- View 
- View
```

And set the parent display property of both the `views` to display `flex`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use TailwindCSS in your React Native project, you can use [tailwindcss-react-native](https://github.com/marklawlor/nativewind) instead

Comment: I am using that only.... all the styling works except for flex-1 :(